# Stream module in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to use a node library which relies on stream (`require('stream')`) within a React Native project.

This is failing with error `stream could not be found within the project` because `stream` is a nodejs package not available in React Native.

What can I do ?

I read that https://github.com/browserify/stream-browserify allows the use of streams in the browser. But how can I make the `require('stream')` in the library (that I don't control) require `stream-browserify` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in my ReactNative project and tried many suggestions, but what finally worked for me was to use the resolver: section in metro.config.js.

My issues were with both stream and crypto.

Here is the resolver section that fixed my problems-

```
resolver: {
  extraNodeModules: {
      stream: require.resolve('readable-stream'),
      crypto: require.resolve('react-native-crypto-js'),
  }
},
```

Comment: where should i add this code?

Comment: @ben you should create `metro.config.js` in root of your project and add it there.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and I solved it by just installing the stream:

```
npm install stream
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error too and ended up installing:

1. `yarn add stream`
2. `yarn add events`

In my case the issues with dependencies started trying to generate an HMAC with this library: https://github.com/crypto-browserify/createHmac